# How Can I Add an Item to an Unordered List without an ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code which is on a pre-existing page and cannot be directly edited (I don't have edit access to the index file). However, the web application allows me to add HTML containers to the page which allows me to indirectly make changes to existing css/html by adding html/css/javascript to these freestanding container objects.

```html
<div class="mst-dropdown-content" style="max-height: 340px;">
  <div class="ToCDropdownMenuContainerContent">
    <ul class="mst-ArrowNavigableList">
      <li class="menu-level-1">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Home" href="XXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Home</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2 selected">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Home, current page" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Main</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Sales" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Sales</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Dashboard" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Dashboard</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to add an additional line item to this pre-existing list, but every attempt I've made has proven unsuccessful.

I thought something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_appendchild) might work, but unfortunately, the list I'm trying to manipulate does not have an ID and therefore I'm having difficulty figuring out how to target said list. Also note that there is only one object with the class "ToCDropdownMenuContainerContent" so for all intents and purposes, that could be used to help target the list. Note that there is another object on the page with the "mst-ArrowNavigableList" class.

(And just covering myself here: end users are instructed to use the latest version of Chrome or IE).

Comment: so if you select the element with a certain class in javascript, it'll return all the elements as an array. just do something like ```$(".mst-ArrowNavigableList")[1].append(your-html-here)```. That will give you the second element in the array of class list items (assuming your html in the question comes after the other element you mentioned)

Comment: I've added an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using plain JavaScript.

1. You can use `document.querySelector` to select the `ul` with `mst-ArrowNavigableList` class.
2. Create the `li` element with `document.createElement`, and `.innerHTML` to create the HTML structure you need inside the `li`.
3. Finally, use `.appendChild` to add to the end of the list.

Working example:

```js
function Add() {
  var element = document.querySelector(".mst-ArrowNavigableList");
  var child = document.createElement("li");
  child.innerHTML = '<a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Dashboard" href="XXXXX"><div class = "menuText" > New Item</div></a>';
  element.appendChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div class="mst-dropdown-content" style="max-height: 340px;">
  <div class="ToCDropdownMenuContainerContent">
    <ul class="mst-ArrowNavigableList">
      <li class="menu-level-1">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Home" href="XXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Home</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2 selected">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Home, current page" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Main</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Sales" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Sales</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-level-2">
        <a class="focusable" role="menuitem" aria-label="Dashboard" href="XXXXX">
          <div class="menuText">Dashboard</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="Add()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```